# Does sample mean converge in distribution to population mean?

Tags: statistics, convergence-divergence

$X_i$ is i.i.d. random variable.
$\overline{X}=\frac{1}{n}\sum X_i$

Can we say that 
$\overline{X} \stackrel{d}{\longrightarrow } E(X)?$

Comment: This is [the law of large numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. What I knew was the law of large numbers was convergence in probability? But how about convergence in distribution?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution. As a side-note: the strong law of large numbers states that the convergence happens almost surely.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much, Mr. Hansen.

Comment: @StefanHansen Why not post your comments as an answer? Possibly with a cautionary statement to the effect that the sample mean exists while $E[X]$ may or may not be defined and so one needs to assume this to apply the law of large numbers; simply saying i.i.d. says nothing about $E[X]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the $X$'s are i.i.d. with *finite* mean ${\rm E}[X]$, then the (strong) law of large numbers states that
$$
\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i\to {\rm E}[X]\quad\text{almost surely and in probability}.
$$
Since convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution your assertion is true. Note that the assumption that ${\rm E}[X]<\infty$ is crucial.

Comment: But what about the central limit theorem? Does it also converge in distribution to a normal random variable?

Answer (score 1):

As Stefan says, it does follow that $\bar{X} \to E(X)$ in distribution since $\bar{X} \to E(X)$ almost surely by the SLLN and convergence a.s. implies convergence in distribution.  The difference between this and the CLT is that the CLT says $$\sqrt{n} (\bar{X} - E(X)) \to N(0, \sigma^2)$$ in distribution, so we are scaling by $\sqrt{n}$ at each step. While it's tempting to conclude from this that $\bar{X} \to N( E(X), \sigma^2 / n)$ in distribution, it's not valid to move the $\sqrt{n}$ term to the right side because it is not constant with respect to $n$.  So the CLT does not contradict the fact that $\bar{X} \to E(X)$ in distribution.